# spring cloud handle multiple concurrent clients and servers

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, versioning, esb, spring-cloud

I am starting with spring cloud provided I already have spring boot applications. The challenge is the service I am developing, need to support multiple versioning for multiple clients. There would be v1 v2 v3 .. services running concurrently and subsequent clients of v1,v2,v3 ... 
A further access is the clients would be having roles so even if a client with v1 roles switch to v2 services, I should be redirecting it to v1 services,may be trying to map the v2 request to v1 (since v2=v1+extra params only, no deletions of param).  How can I leverage spring cloud and related techs to handle this or a solution based on enterprise service bus would be more suitable.
Thankyou for any feedbacks, really appreciate any support for this.

Comment: Rohit does that help?

Comment: Yes @PaulJohn, thats a good start, I had experience with ESB handling the api versioning with appropriate routing, Eureka seems to take it to next level where discovery is also gets smarter.

Comment: glad it worked. would be great if you accept the answer if that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIth microservices, versioning can always be a problem once you start to scale and deploy multitude of services. Netflix Eureka can help (which does service discovery) and lookup is a very useful tool that can help tackle such a problem. Plus it's used @ netflix with their huge scale of microservices. http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/09/eureka.html

Spring Cloud Netflixhttp://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/ comes with Eureka and makes it very easy to implement microservices based on the netflix stack.
You could register services with version number as part of the service name, and thus have the client's lookup the appropriate services they are supposed to call (with their versions).
Here is a sample implementation of a spring cloud netflix microservice - https://github.com/bijukunjummen/spring-cloud-ping-pong-sample